# Why isn’t the hostname command getting the FQDN from /etc/hostname?

Tags: rhel, systemd, hostname

I set the hostname.

```
# more /etc/hostname
kafka01.ocff4.com
```

The hostname is still as follows.

```
hostname
kafka01
```

I restart using the following command.

```
 systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed
```

But still, `hostname` does not show the FQDN.

```
hostname
kafka01
```

Why did `systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed` not take affect? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your /etc/sysconfig/network file.  If your hostname isn't present in the file, place the following line in it:
    hostname kafka01.ocff4.com

You'll also have to "sudo hostname kafka01.ocff4.com" at the command line to make the change take affect immediatly, or restart to make the change take affect.

Comment: not in  /etc/syconfig/network

Comment: You might have to enter "sudo hostname kafka01.ocff4.com" at the command line, or restart to make the change take affect.

Comment: With systemd you should be using hostnamectl

Comment: why -  systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed not take affect??  is it a bug?